# Which kind of optimization problem on integers is the following?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm not asking for a solution, I would just need to know what type of optimization is the following problem? Find $\mathbf{m}$ that minimizes:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left|\frac{1}{\sin^{m}\left(\frac{k}{N}\pi\right)} \prod_{i=1}^{m} \left|\sin\left(\frac{k\ m_i}{N}\pi\right)\right| - h_{k}\right|
$$

where $ 0 \leq h_k \leq 1$ is known,  $\mathbf{m} = [m_1, ... , m_m]$ , $N = \sum_{i=1}^{m} m_i - m +1$ and $m_i$ is integer, $i = 1, 2, ..., m$.

In other words $\mathbf{m}$ is a vector of $m$ integers and there are $N$ "points" for which the "distance" needs to be minimized. The distance has been written with absolute values, but it could be also expressed as a quadratic function. Where I am completely lost is if there is some theory about this kind of optimizations on integers and what is to be considered a costraint and what an objective or cost. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: The value of $m$ (the number of unknowns $m_i$) and $N$ (that you call "points") are known *a priori* right? So the equality $N = (\sum m_i) - m +1$ is to be considered as a constraint on the unknowns $m_i$.

Comment: Yes and no... $N$ can be considered as known "a priori" but not necessarily $m$ (the number of unknowns $m_i$), anyway I would also be more than interested in any hint even in the case both $m$ and $N$ are considered to be known a priori.

Comment: Have you tried to solve some edge cases? For example $N = 1$, $N = 2$, ... or $m = 1$, $m = 2$, ...

Comment: Nope, the practical use case would be for relatively large $N$ (hundreds or few thousands) and  relatively small $m$ (4 to 8 or 10 maybe, but it could be more in principle). I am completely out of my backyard with this, so any hint towards the right direction would be important! Thanks!